# UITableViewCell setSelected:animated: not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

This is driving me crazy. I've looked here on S.O. for what I thought was a simple answer but couldn't find one.

In my custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{   
    // Configure the view for the selected state
    if (selected) {        
        [self.languageLevelNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];        
    }
    else {        
        [self.languageLevelNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorMessageCountZero]];
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of the controller:

```
 if ([level integerValue] == indexPath.row) {

        [cell setSelected:YES];
    }
```

I've inserted break points and `selected == YES` is getting passed for the correct cell, and the `if` statement is being executed when it should be, but the text never gets set to `blackColor`.

Comment: UITableViewCell's `-setSelected:` does not call `-setSelected:animated:NO` internally.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to set your cell as selected use the method `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` like this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method of your table view

Objective-C

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

swift 4

```
tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
```

Comment: Calling this method in `viewWillAppear`did it for me. Calling it in `viewDidLoad` had no effect, calling it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` seems overkill to me (swift 5 / 2020).

Answer (score 77):

For the cell to appear selected, you have to call `-setSelected:animated:` from within `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` like so:

Objective C:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (/* should be selected */) {
        [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];  // required, as noted below
    }
}
```

Swift 3:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (/* should be selected */) {
        cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)  // required, as noted below
    }
}
```

Calling `-setSelected` from anywhere else has no effect.

Why?
After initializing or dequeueing a cell, but before displaying it, the table view calls a private method called `-_configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:` which, among other things, sets the cell's `selected` property to NO.  The delegate's `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` gets called after this, letting you set anything needed for display.

Comment: Seeing this... Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Important information about how tableview cells work!

Comment: very important as well, we also need to call `tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .Top)` otherwise that cell becomes unselectable (the delegate doesn't respond to neither `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` nor `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`)

Comment: I'd like to know how you both figured that out.  I wish the Apple doc had that information.. 1) to call setSelected within willDisplayCell because of dequeue and 2) calling selectRowAtIndexPath.  Great job.  I had written my own selection code because I couldn't default the rows to selected.

Comment: @LevinsonTechnologies If you have a custom subclass of UITableViewCell you can override -setSelected: and put a breakpoint on it. Then you can see exactly when it gets called in the process of dequeuing and displaying.

Comment: *didDeselectRowAtIndexPath not  work* with this solution

Comment: I don't think you should call `tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)` in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. Instead you should handle the cases completely: `cell.setSelected(/* put the boolean expression here*/, animated: false)` and this way get rid of the if-statement.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you don't need to call both cell.setSelected AND tableView.selectRow. You only need call tableView.selectRow which works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSIndexPath* selectedCellIndexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:number_row  inSection:0];
[self tableView:tableViewList didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];
[tableViewList selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call cell's setSelected method.Apple hope that we set cell's selected status through two functions ,one is didSelectRowAtIndexPath ,the other is didDeselectRowAtIndexPath,they always occurr in pairs.To solve this problem,we just call   two functions:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[self tableView:self.leftTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.leftTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```